# How to use handlebars in html

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have created a custom break function in handlebar and am trying to use it in html. While rendering the html to browser, it is not showing the expected result. Please correct me if tags have been misplaced.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

  <script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
     {{#break students}}
     {{name}} has passed in {{passingYear}}.<br>
  {{/break}}      
  </script>

</head>
<body>

{{name}} has passed in {{passingYear}}.<br>

<script>
Handlebars.registerHelper("break", function(data,options) {

  var context = {
  "students": [{
    "name": "mrinal",
    "passingYear": 2013
  }, {
    "name": "raman",
    "passingYear": 2016
  },    
    {
    "name": "John",
    "passingYear": 2018 
  }]
}

  var len = data.length;
  var returnData = "";

 // custom break function 
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if(data[i].passingYear<2015){
      return  returnData = returnData + options.fn(data[i]);
      i=len+1;
    } else{
      return  returnData = returnData + options.fn(data[i]);
    }}
})
var template = $('handlebars-demo').html();
var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);

var html = templateScript(context);
$(document.body).append(html);
</script>


</body>
</html>

expected result: 
mrinal has passed in 2013.
```

Please look into the code and share if any corrections need to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many mistakes :

- You've mixed the declaration of the handlebar helper (not function even if you define the function attached to your helper) with the compile and rendering of your data. Put out your context and the things that do not need to be in the helper.
- You don't declare jquery but you use it ($) you have to include jquery
- You call jquery to get the html from your template but with a bad selector : you have to put a # character in front of your selector if you want the id that is following the sharp character.

The working version follows :

```js
var context = {
  "students": [
    {
      "name": "mrinal",
      "passingYear": 2013
    }, 
    {
      "name": "raman",
      "passingYear": 2016
    },    
    {
      "name": "John",
      "passingYear": 2018 
    }
  ]
} 

Handlebars.registerHelper("break", function(data,options) {
  var len = data.length;
  var returnData = "";
 // custom break function 
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(data[i].passingYear<2015){
        return  returnData = returnData + options.fn(data[i]);
        i=len+1;
      } else {
        return  returnData = returnData + options.fn(data[i]);
      }
  }
});

var template = $('#handlebars-demo').html();
var templateScript = Handlebars.compile(template);
var html = templateScript(context);
$("#placeholder").append(html);
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.1/handlebars.min.js"></script>

  <script id="handlebars-demo" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#break students}}
     {{name}} has passed in {{passingYear}}.<br>
  {{/break}}      
  
  {{name}} has passed in {{passingYear}}.<br>
  </script>

<div id="placeholder"></div>

expected result: 
mrinal has passed in 2013.
```

Comment: Hey Chris, Thanks for the prompt reply. Just wanted to know the following: i) Can we not write a single html file with handlebar helper in it ? ii) In above answer of yours, are there two files ?

Comment: 1/- you can write everything in a single html file just put the script part between <script></script> tags 2/- Just one file, I wanted to make a snippet that work in stackoverflow and it split the code in html and js but you can put it in a single file

Comment: Hey Chris, can we use create a custom break function using for each loop in place of for loop in the code above ?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you want to do. Reformulate your question. I suggest that you put a new question intead of asking it in this one also, this one is solved.

Comment: I mean, in place of using for loop in custom break as below, can i use for each to iterate over an array ?                                                                                   
      for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(data[i].passingYear<2015){
        return  returnData = returnData + options.fn(data[i]);
        i=len+1;
      } else {
        return  returnData = returnData + options.fn(data[i]);
      }
  }
});

Comment: Usually I'd rather use a {{#each}}{{/each}} loop in my template and write a custom helper function on my element rather than doing a helper that iterate on my data. But yes you can do it

Comment: Can you please show how to use {{#each}}{{/each}} loop ? That would be gr8.

Comment: do you expect only one line in the result or multiples lines ?

Comment: Only one line would be ok.

Comment: look at my other answer